# Stop Device orientation

Tags: uideviceorientation

While running my app I get errors which indicate that rotation notifications are being sent and crashing the app. Is there a way I can stop all rotation events from being sent to see if I can stop the crashes. Also is there a good overview of how these events should be handled. Do I have to handle them separately in in controllers or in all views. For the moment I would be quite happy to lock in portrait.

I have tried calling [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGenerating Device OrientationNotifications];
but I am still getting device Orientation DidChange events unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop rotation notifications, nor should you try to.

The notifications aren't causing your crash, you must have some bad code in there.

Paste your exact error from the console and the code for the view controller where it's happening. My guess is that you've written a rotation handler method that doesn't work, possibly without realising it.

You can lock in portrait by creating a view controller base class that has this method, then using it as the superclass for all your other view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I have been looking back at what I have changed recently and I added a temporary uiview to try to get MBProgressHUD to work, I am removing this view after use but it seems it is still being sent a notification (I cometed out the code and no crashes. Should I be removing notifications for this view?

Comment: You need to get rid of any NSNotification handlers relating to rotation if you aren't using them.

Comment: Commented HUB back in and commented out all 'Orientation' callbacks and I still get a crash. I am presuming it is something I have done writing in implementing the HUD stuff. Thanks.

Comment: WHat is the log message you are getting - what is the selector that is causing the crash?

Comment: 0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x31eb0fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                     0x32e26508 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
2   CoreFoundation                 0x33e60570 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 64
3   CoreFoundation                 0x33dec0c8 _CFXNotificationPost + 1400
4   Foundation                     0x32d9a3f4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
5   UIKit                          0x37017c08 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 208