# Registering for UIDeviceOrientation

Tags: ios, uidevice, uideviceorientation

I want to detect the current orientation of the device.

So, I used the a line of code

Note: It gives me orientation even if I have not register it

```
-(IBAction) deviceOrientationChanged:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Device Orientation= %d",[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
}
```

When I change the orientation, on a button click event I get the device orientation.

But, the [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) says you need to register it first, then use the above code.

Note: In the below code I have registered device to receive device orientation notification

```
-(IBAction) deviceOrientationChanged:(id) sender{

    if(![[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]){
        //This statement is called very time when I click on the button. I expected to execute only once.
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    }
    NSLog(@"Device Orientation= %d",[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);
}
```

So, I am not able get through the perfect way to get the Device Orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I think Your if condition is wrong ;
U have it as
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
It should be

if(  **!**   [[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])

Comment: Thnks, I have corrected the code but, now its not entering the if condition for registering the device. I don't why it's returning TRUE. I have checked in my entire code, there is no other place where I am registering from device Orientation.

Comment: Registering for notifications is different from generating the notifications. Normally if you are planning to use device orientation notifications in the app delegate or in an appropriate place you will make the call beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications on the UIDevice and will make the endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications in another appropriate place when U no longer need the notifications. This is only the initial setup for deviceOrientaion notification.

Answer (score 1):

Registering for notifications is different from generating the notifications. Normally if you are planning to use device orientation notifications in the app delegate or in an appropriate place you will make the call beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications on the UIDevice and will make the endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications in another appropriate place when U no longer need the notifications. This is only the initial setup for deviceOrientaion notification.

To get these notification is in you controllers or object U have to us the Notification Center. U register for the notification UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myObject selector:@selector(deviceRotated:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]

and remove it from the notification center when U dont need it or in the dealloc of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the device from generating `UIViewController` rotation notifications. See the question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239258/stop-device-orienation?rq=1)

What the document you linked to is referring to, are `NSNotificationCenter` notifications.

Comment: It says "The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications." where property to refers to "orientation" property of UIDevice